# Why did the Mizbeach grow 40 times?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, shiurim-measurements, mizbeach-altar

The main, [Bronze Altar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%AA#%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95) in the Mishkan was 5 Amos wide. It was also portable.

In the [Temple(s)](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94#%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F), it grew to 32 Amot wide - 6.4 time in width and 41 times in footage<sup>1</sup>.

*EDIT: according to [JoelK's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99976/15579), both measures were given explicitly by G-d to Moses and passed on to Shlomo.*

The population in the wilderness counted over 600K households, and hardly the Jewish population in Eretz Israel ever reached that number again to necessitate such expansion of the Altar to accommodate for additional offerings (my guess, acc. to [here](http://www.ldolphin.org/popul.html)).

I assume that there were no additional sacrifices in the Temples over what was practices in the desert (or maybe people sinned much more :).

What was the reason for the Altar in the Temple to be 40 times bigger than one in the Mishkan?

---

<sup>1</sup> I understand it started with 28 Ama in the First and grew to 32 subsequently in the late Second.

Comment: Everything was bigger in the Beis HaMikdash in comparison to the Mishnah. This isn’t unique to the Mizbeiach.

Comment: @DonielF דחאו בקש. 1. if it served the same role and quantities, why was it 40 times bigger, why wasn't the original 5x5 sufficient? 2. Please explain why everything was bigger then?

Comment: If you edit your question accordingly I'd be happy to post such an answer. In the meantime, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99974/ is somewhat related.

Comment: @DonielF Voila, thanks for the linked question!

Comment: We have censuses which explicitly reject your claim in your fourth paragraph. The population in the desert measured ~600,000 men (Bamidbar ch. 1), while the population several years before the First Temple was built was ~1.1 million men (Divrei Hayamim 1:21:5, with Pesikta Rabbasi 11 to resolve the contradiction from Shmuel 2:24:9). It doesn't fully answer your question, as one would expect the altar to be just twice the area to accommodate twice the population, whereas this is significantly larger.

Comment: @DonielF I join your consensus, but this can't be a real number by any scientifical measures. Anyway, the measures were already known to Moses. 2. Let's take a different route - ware the Temple's Altar functions different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94775/discussion-between-donielf-and-al-berko).