# Why Temples' dimensions were different from the Mishkan?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, shiurim-measurements, mishkan-tabernacle

After asking ["why-did-the-mizbeach-grow-40-times"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104657/why-did-the-mizbeach-grow-40-times), I realized (thanks JoelK) that both measurements were [dictated by G-d](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99976/15579) (it's unclear to whom: Moses, David or other prophets). See also [Yalkut Shimoni 1081](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99982/15579) (thanks Meir).

Both the Mishkan and the Temple served the same purpose, but the Temples' dimensions were significantly bigger on practically everything. As the population varied greatly I assume that populational fluctuations can't count for those differences, already given by G-d.

What is the reason those two holy dwellings were so different in dimensions? Do the variations hint on changes in G-d's manifestations, or some spiritual representations?

Comment: 1: "I assume that populational fluctuations can't count for those differences" Why not? Shouldn't a larger population necessitate a larger Temple? 2: Mishkan was temporary, Bais Hamikdash was 'permanent'. It seems logical to me that a temporary structure would be smaller and a permanent structure would be bigger.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Would be bigger because...? If we assume those measurements are symbolic, what the difference would be?

Comment: Maybe: For the same reason your laptop is smaller than your PC; to make it portable?

Comment: @DannySchoemann My laptop is the same size, you mean the screen? Aron was the same, the Menorah didn't grow, the sacrifices weren't added, so why bigger? Just to make impression?

Comment: Yes! To look impressive. (Though the "empty space" was filled up with duplicate (unused) Keilim.)