# "A prophet cannot renew Halachot" rule limitations

Tags: halacha-theory, nevua-prophecy

[Divrei HaYamim](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.28.11?lang=bi) describes the process of building of the first Temple, hinting that the exact plan was prophesied:

> וַיִּתֵּן דָּוִיד לִשְׁלֹמֹה בְנוֹ אֶת־תַּבְנִית הָאוּלָם וְאֶת־בָּתָּיו וְגַנְזַכָּיו וַעֲלִיֹּתָיו וַחֲדָרָיו הַפְּנִימִים וּבֵית הַכַּפֹּרֶת׃ וְתַבְנִית כֹּל אֲשֶׁר הָיָה בָרוּחַ עִמּוֹ לְחַצְרוֹת בֵּית־ה' וּלְכָל־הַלְּשָׁכוֹת סָבִיב לְאֹצְרוֹת בֵּית הָאֱלֹהִים וּלְאֹצְרוֹת הַקֳּדָשִׁים׃ ...
>
> **הַכֹּל בִּכְתָב מִיַּד ה' עָלַי הִשְׂכִּיל כֹּל מַלְאֲכוֹת הַתַּבְנִית׃**
>
> David gave his son Solomon the plan of the porch and its houses, ... and of the treasuries of the holy things;...
> **“All this that the LORD made me understand by His hand on me, I give you in writing—the plan of all the works.”**

There are multiple approaches to interpreting the last line, Rashi says that Shmuel learned that from the Torah, but others (Malbim, Radak) says it was prophesied, either by David himself (the Pshat of the verse) or by preceding prophets (Shmuel, Nathan, etc) that passed that knowledge to David.

This question only addresses the latter interpretation: if a prophet comes and says he received the measures of the about-to-be-built Temple from G-d, do we treat it as a prophesy and accept it or as a Halacha and reject?

And, therefore, what are the limits of what we can or cannot accept from a prophet based on the aforementioned rule?

Comment: What "renewal" of halachot do you see going on here?

Comment: @JoelK Temple measures seem to be Halochos, don't you think?

Comment: But why do you think they are being ‘renewed’? This is the first time that a Temple was built

Comment: If the measurements were to only be used for the first Temple (as opposed to the Tabernacles and subsequent Temples), presumably the commandment is only, therefore, temporary.  The rule of "*ein navi rashai l'chadesh*..." is only regarding the eternal/timeless commandments of the Mosaic code, not *temporary* commandments of the minor prophets.

Comment: It would be helpful perhaps if you sourced/explained a bit the rule you're asking about, e.g.: "אלה הדברים. שאין הנביא רשאי לחדש דבר מעתה" (שבת ק"ד ע"א).

"אלה המצוות, אין נביא רשאי לחדש עוד דבר מעתה" (תורת כהנים סו"פ י"ג).  רמב"ם הל' יסודי התורה פ"ט ה"א

Comment: see also: https://www.academia.edu/5873620/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%9A_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: http://www.torahbase.org/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%93/

Comment: http://asif.co.il/?wpfb_dl=2446

Comment: Not sure Temples measurements are halakhos. There is a difference between saying these are the limits of the dimensions of a kosher Heikhal and these are the dimensions of this particular Heikhal. For example, for all the debate over whether the menorah had curved or straight arms, either would be kosher. It could even be that (barring metalurgy questions about straight arms), different menoros over the centuries differed on that very point!